# Wordpress on Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Server: Only Home Page works

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis-7.5

I recently moved a Wordpress site from Apache Server to Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Server, the problem is, when moving to IIS Server, only homepage works. When I go to archive page or single page, it returns 404 error. I think it because IIS doesn't understand the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` in htaccess rewrite wordpress)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So I tried to convert the htaccess above to web.cofig like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But it returns 500 error. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I have to install the module for IIS for URL rewrite.
http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file will not work for IIS Server.Instead of .htaccess you need to write web.coonfig file you can get more help [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)